# Rails devise sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, devise

I am trying to write an API for a mobile application which authenticates using JSON. I am using Devise for the authentication in my Rails app.

On trying this:

curl -v -b cookie.file -c cookie.file -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user" : {"email":"MYUSER" , "password":"MYPASSWORD" }}' `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json`

the rails server logs shows - WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

As per this link, https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/issues/3041, it is a simple warning message that is displayed for all requests. But then I'm not able to access json response for any other request after this call. It gives me an error : {"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}

for this request

curl -L http://localhost:3000/posts.json

Answer (score 0):

CSRF token check will happen for all request. Please have a look on below link. I hope that will solve your problem.

see link
https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/issues/3041

Comment: It says to skip the CSRF token, but I don't want to skip it as it will increase vulnerability to attacks.  Is it not possible to get CSRF token and pass it with json request from my client iphone app?